# How to select list item using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to select a song from the playlist, but selection doesn't work as it should, because, when I click for the first time it returns "null" when I click on the second time it selects an item, but for some reason, when I keep clicking on different items I always get a previous item value, and I don't know why.

```
//Here is my action from redux:

import {FETCH_PLAYLIST_SUCCESS, FETCH_PLAYLIST_FAILURE, FETCH_PLAYLIST_REQUEST, SELECT_TRACK} from './types'
import {PREV, PLAY, PAUSE, NEXT, TOGGLE_TRACK} from './types';
import axios from "axios/index";

export const getPlayList = id => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_PLAYLIST_REQUEST});
    axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.deezer.com/search/track?q=red+hot+chili+peppers').then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PLAYLIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
          playlist: response.data.data,
          currentTrack: response.data.data[0]
        }
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PLAYLIST_FAILURE,
        payload: err,
      });
    })
  }
};

//func which takes index of list item
export  const selectTrack = (i) =>{
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: SELECT_TRACK,
      payload: i
    });
  }
}

//reducer
 case SELECT_TRACK:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedTrack: state.playList[action.payload],
      };

//click handler in container component
 handleClick = (index) => {
    this.props.selectTrack(index);
    console.log(this.props.playlist.selectedTrack);
    console.log(index);
  };

//how I'm using it in playlist component
<Playlist handleClick={this.handleClick} tracks={this.props.playlist.playList}/>

//Playlist component 
function PlayList(props) {
  const {i,handleClick,currentSongIndex,tracks,isSelected,} = props;
  return (
    <div className="playlist-container">
      <div className="playlist">
        <ul>
          {
            tracks.map((track, index) => (
              <Track
                isSelected={isSelected}
                index={index}
                key={track.id}
                id={track.id}
                title_short={track.title}
                duration={track.duration}
                clickHandler={ () => handleClick(index)}
              />
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See how it works on screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon item click, you are dispatching the action in the click handler of the container. The props in the handler at the time of console.log is still the old props. The new props will arrive only once redux updates state and component updates its props via the react lifecycle methods.

I am guessing you have not set any intial state in the reducer which might be the reason why the first value is coming as null.

Try adding the same statement : `console.log(this.props.playlist.selectedTrack)` in the render method. You should see the updated prop

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I put `console.log(this.props.playlist.selectedTrack)` in render method,and it updated the value as it should

Answer (score 1):

@Easwar is correct (above) that your debugging logic is problematic.

With respect to the core problem, I don't see where some of your important props are passed in.  You have:

```
const {i,handleClick,currentSongIndex,tracks,isSelected,} = props;
```

In your `PlayList` component, but you're invoking it like this:

```
<Playlist handleClick={this.handleClick} tracks={this.props.playlist.playList}/>
```

Where are `currentSongIndex` and `isSelected` passed in?  Your trouble is likely there.  It looks like they'll evaluate to `null` in `<Playlist>`'s render method.

Comment: Thank you for the response! 
I will take a note of your comment!